# Issues utilizing full page width with jsPDF when creating a PDF from HTML template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf

I am trying to create a nicely formatted PDF email attachment from an HTML template that I have using the [jsPDF NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf).

The HTML displays fine in the browser and in an email, but jsPDF seems to be inserting line breaks at every word.

This is an example that is having the same issue as my real template:

```
    import { jsPDF } from 'jsPDF';    

    const pdf: jsPDF = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'a4');
    const newHtml: string = `
      <div style="text-align: center; margin: auto; width: 100%;">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Ea labore laboriosam officia rem, soluta velit. Consectetur ipsum
          odit quisquam sequi. Assumenda earum fugit iste obcaecati
          placeat quas unde vitae voluptate!
        </p>
      </div>
    `;
    pdf.html(newHtml, {
      callback: (doc: jsPDF) => {
        doc.save('testPdf.pdf');
      }
    })
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:
[image: PDF Output]

It seems like the page is being squashed down to about 1/5th of the width, and I would like full utilization of the page.

Thank you!

Comment: After more digging, I seem to have found a workaround for the issue [here](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2909)